# Compatible h2 version for Hibernate 6.2.6-Final

Tags: hibernate, h2

What is the compatible h2 version for Hibernate 6.2.6-Final?

I tried the latest h2 version. It's not creating the database and is not generating an id. Which will be the valid version to use.

I tried a different version, but still there wasn't any outcome.

Comment: h6 should compatible with the latest h2 version. so don't think it is the h2 and hibernate version compatibility problem. It is more about your code problem.

Comment: Can you provide the part of your build script that describes this dependency?

Comment: I tried with h2:1.4.200 its working now 
Thanks